# Does WSO2 ESB works on soap 1.1 by default?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I just want to know that does WSO2 ESB by default support on soap 1.1? How to make it work on soap 1.2? Is there any global property by which I can change all the deployed services to make it work on soap 1.2?

Thanks in Advance

Regards,
Shri

Hi Thanks for your response. but I get below error when try 1.2 Soap request from the SOAP UI.

```
                                                        [2016-08-10 10:53:41,744] ERROR - NativeWorkerPool [msg_id=urn:uuid:4abc1b45-c6a8-4f92-9559-169d3dab403f] Uncaught exception
```

org.apache.axiom.om.impl.exception.OMBuilderException: detail unsupported element in SOAPFault element
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.SOAP12BuilderHelper.handleEvent(SOAP12BuilderHelper.java:175)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.constructNode(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:428)

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 ESB [supports both](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Features) by default. For example, when you create a proxy service in ESB, it exposes both SOAP 1.1 and SOAP 1.2 endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this error happens when using SOAP 1.2 while communicating between .Net applications and Axis2. So far the only solution I have seen is to force the use of SOAP 1.1.

See also:
[Mention of error](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/axis-java-user/200709.mbox/%3Cs6e7a9b1.052@health.qld.gov.au%3E)

Apparently the definition of the SOAPfault changed slightly between versions, most importantly the capitalisation of certain elements, including the detail element.  The error suggests that the received message includes the  element, which is in accordance with SOAP 1.1, while in SOAP 1.2 it should be a  element. For more detail, check this [site](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGMCP_5.3.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.webservices.doc/concepts/soap/dfhws_fault.html)